# Spotify Api returning undefined object when trying to get playlist tracks with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, spotify

```
import axios from "axios";
```

import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
export default function Dashboard({token}) {

```
const [playlist_id, setPlaylistId] = useState([]);
const [href, setHref] = useState([]);
const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([]);
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const getTracks = async (token) =>{
    const {tracks} = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/4FteCV6SQS8yKc6pzFlZnv/tracks", {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
        },
        params: {
            market: "US",
            limit: 50,
            offset: 0
        }
        })
        console.log({tracks})
    }
   
    setIsMounted(true);
    //getPlaylists(token);
    getTracks(token);
}, [])

if(isMounted)
return(
    <div className="Dashboard">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
)};
```

I am trying to get the items in a public spotify playlist through axios, but the request retrieves an undefined object every time. Should I be using a different token with a special scope? Is there something I am missing with my API call?

These are the strings I am using to retrieve the original token:

```
const CLIENT_ID = "00c7cd96ee6940879762750970dc5863"
const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000"
const AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
const RESPONSE_TYPE = "token"
```

I was able to make a similar call to retrieve all the playlists of a user and the response was `const {data}`

Comment: hi, post code instead image of code

Comment: Welcome! Please see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - many reasons why you should provide formatted text instead of images of text.

Comment: Aside from that: Please edit to include more details, such as the exact error you get, the payload details, etc. Tl;dr provide as much detail as possible to help others help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.get` returns a [`Response` object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). That object doesn't have `tracks` property.

You probably wanted to do:

```
const {data: tracks} = axios.get(/* url */)
```